# I need help regarding dynamic SQL and dynamically setting the table name in a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, sql-function

So, i need to create a function that returns the count of the lines in a table, the table name must be specified by the user. This is the code i have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datiInTab( table regclass )
RETURNS NUMERIC(5) AS
$$
DECLARE
num NUMERIC(5);
cmd VARCHAR(1000):='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ';
BEGIN
EXECUTE cmd || table;
RETURN num;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SELECT * FROM datiInTab(corsi);
```

And this is the error that returns after i execute:

```
ERROR: ERRORE: la colonna "corsi" non esiste 
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM datiInTab(corsi); ^ SQL state: 42703 Character: 25
```

Meaning that the column "corsi" doesn't exist.
I debugged as much as i could and the only conclusion is that i don't really know what i need to do in order to make use of this dynamic call.

edit: regclass was a last minute addition, after trying with a simple varchar, that returned the same exact error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't name a variable table. it is a reserved word

and you have to pass a string else postgres thinks you want to pass a column

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datiInTab( table1 regclass )
> RETURNS NUMERIC(5) AS
> $$
> DECLARE
> num NUMERIC(5);
> cmd VARCHAR(1000):='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ';
> BEGIN
> EXECUTE cmd || table1;
> RETURN num;
> END;
> $$
> LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM datiInTab('corsi');
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  relation "corsi" does not exist
> ```

LINE 1: SELECT * FROM datiInTab('corsi');
^

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=132c0c98fa2ed9101fa04b48c7aa1ac9)*